# ignore a double quote (") while using read_csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, read.csv

```
================================================== ====
Title: Whole case
Location: oyuri
From: Aki 
Date: 2018/11/30 (Friday) 11:55:29
================================================== =====
1: Aki 
2018/12/05 (Wed) 17:33:17
"
An approval notice has been sent.
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------
2: Aki
2018/12/06 (Thursday) 17:14:30
I was notified by Mr. Id, the agent of the other party.

-------------------------------------------------- ------------------
3: kano, etc.
2018/12/07 (Friday) 11:44:45
Please call rito.
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------
```

This Is my text file which I have converted to a CSV
the only problem I'm facing is when there is a double quote(") in the file (for example here in this file in entry number 1 )
how can I ignore the double quote while reading the CSV file?
the separator I'm using while reading the file is \n

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename ,sep='\n', header=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv' ,sep='\n', header=None, quotechar="'")
print(df)

#output:
                                                    0
0   ==============================================...
1                                   Title: Whole case
2                                     Location: oyuri
3                                           From: Aki
4                  Date: 2018/11/30 (Friday) 11:55:29
5   ==============================================...
6                                              1: Aki
7                           2018/12/05 (Wed) 17:33:17
8                                                   "
9                   An approval notice has been sent.
10  ----------------------------------------------...
11                                             2: Aki
12                     2018/12/06 (Thursday) 17:14:30
13  I was notified by Mr. Id, the agent of the oth...
14  ----------------------------------------------...
15                                      3: kano, etc.
16                       2018/12/07 (Friday) 11:44:45
17                                  Please call rito.
18  ----------------------------------------------...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try passing `quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE` or (if that doesn't work) playing with `quotechar`?

```
import csv

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\n', header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Answer (score 0):

To ignore a double quote `"` while using `read_csv` include `quotechar='"'`

```py
pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV, sep=',', engine='python', quotechar='"')
```

*You can also check other options here:*

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#